# Cannot open Speed Kit on Plesk

Tags: baqend

I purchased an extension and then I open in Plesk I get below error:

CentOs 7, Plesk 17.5

```
Call to a member function getDomains()
License.php
Line    85


[2018-12-06 04:46:55.712] ERR [panel] Call to a member function getDomains() on null:
0: /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/baqend/library/License/License.php:85
        Baqend\PleskExtension\SpeedKit\License\License->getAllowedDomainCount()
1: /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/baqend/library/Service/Limits.php:77
        Baqend\PleskExtension\SpeedKit\Service\Limits->getSpeedKitDomainLimit()
```